# Apply a never_cache to a flatpage view

Tags: django, django-urls, django-cache

I want to create a home view that is the same as a home view but does not cache it.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.flatpages.views',
    url(r'^$', 'flatpage', {'url': '/'}, name='home'),
)
```

Something like this

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.flatpages.views',
    url(r'^$', 'flatpage', {'url': '/'}, name='home'),
    url(r'^new/$', never_cache('flatpage', {'url': '/'}), name='nocache_home'),
)
```

Clearly this won't work but does anyone know the trick which would enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

def never_cache_patterns(prefix, *args):
    pattern_list = [], tterns,
    for t in args:
        if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)): 
            t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)
        elif isinstance(t, RegexURLPattern):
            t.add_prefix(prefix)

        t._callback = never_cache(t.callback)
        pattern_list.append(t)

    return pattern_list


urlpatterns = never_cache_patterns('',
    (r'foo/$', 'myview')
)
```

Comment: Thanks Catherine - I actually saw this but didn't catch how to use it.  That was the piece which was needed.  BTW - I cleaned up your version as it had ununsed vars in it.